# Error installing protocol buffers compiler (protoc) with java in linux

Tags: java, linux, protocol-buffers

I tried to install protocol buffer compiler  - Java in Ubuntu through reading README.txt file .
First i typed the following commands:

```
./configure
```

then

```
make
```

then

```
make check
```

then

```
make install
```

then

```
protoc --java_out=src/main/java -I../src \../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto
```

In this last step i have a problem that I don't know which paths should I put in this command.

Answer (score 0):

```
protoc(1) --java_out=src/main/java(2) -I../src(3) ../src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto(4)
```

1. **protoc:** main program
2. **--java_out=OUT_DIR:** Generate Java source files in OUT_DIR path (must exists).
3. **-I (--proto_path) optional:** Specify the directory in which to search for imports.  May be specified multiple times; directories will be searched in order.  If not given, the current working directory is used.
4. Your **.proto** descriptor file.

But you can simplify the command line with

```
protoc --java_out=src/main/java /path/to/my/proto/myproto.proto
```